# MySQL date calculation for Japanese fiscal year

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get a set of results based on the Japanese fiscal year start, which is April 1 (could be set to different dates, of course). But the code below returns 2017 for @fiscalYear, never 2018. Am I declaring/managing the variables wrong? Please advise.

```
SET @currentMonth = MONTH(CURDATE());

IF @currentMonth < 4 THEN SET @fiscalYear = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
ELSEIF @currentMonth > 3 THEN SET @fiscalYear = YEAR(CURDATE());
END IF;

SET @fiscalYearStart = CONCAT(@fiscalYear, '-04-01');

SELECT @currentMonth, @fiscalYear, @fiscalYearStart;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're doing something wrong when you set `@fiscalYear`...

```
SET @currentMonth = MONTH(CURDATE());

SET @fiscalYear = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL IF(@currentMonth > 3, 0, 1) YEAR));

SET @fiscalYearStart = CONCAT(@fiscalYear, '-04-01');

SELECT @currentMonth, @fiscalYear, @fiscalYearStart;
```

Comment: Thanks Kosh Very, that works great. Can you tell me what I'm doing funny with my initial code?

Comment: There is nothing funny. Please take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html. You're using `IF` statement for stored programs, but your code is not a stored program. Also you do not have to have `ELSEIF` condition since you have to check if it's April or not. So if-else would be enough.